# PHP Drop Down Menu to Select the Subject for an email

Tags: php, html

I have created a php page to send an email, however, I'd like to create a drop down menu to select a suffix for the subject of the email.

Example: 
Drop menu options: dog, cat, duck.

If cat is selected,
an email is sent with the subject: "I am a cat"

Here is the code I'm using to send the email:

```
<?php
 $to = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
 $subject = "I am a cat";
 $body = "test";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<font size=\"18\" face='Arial'>Email successfully 

sent!");
  } else {
   echo("<h1>Email delivery failed…</h1>");
  }
 ?>
```

How can I alter the code create the menu?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is very fundamental. Do you already know how HTML forms work? How PHP superglobal `$_GET, $_POST` work? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Just complementing what Michael said, maybe you want to take a look at this example as well: http://www.php-example.com/2011/05/php-html-form-select-box-example.html

Comment: I would advise a tutorial on modern HTML, at least XHTML, then HTML5. I see a lack of basics, and the horrid <font> tag.

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form method="POST">
    <select name="drop_menu">
      <option value="dog">Dog</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat</option>
      <option value="duck">Duck</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Form" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
    $to = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
    $subject = "I am a ".$_POST["drop_menu"];
    $body = "test";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        echo("<font size=\"18\" face='Arial'>Email successfully sent!</font>");
    } else {
        echo("<h1>Email delivery failed…</h1>");
    }
?>
```

EDIT:

I took the liberty of adding the complete file for you, so it works out of the box. I commented some lines.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Test page</title>
  </head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .msg {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: "Arial";
    }
    .msg.error {
      color:red;
    }
    .msg.success {
      color:green;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
  <?php
    // Checking if form has been posted
    if ($_POST) {
      // Email Address destination
      $to = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
      // Email subject
      $subject = "I am a ".$_POST["drop_menu"];
      // Email body
      $body = "test";
      // Mailing
      if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        // Successfully sent
        echo('<div class="msg success">Email successfully sent!</div>');
      } else {
        // Failed
        echo('<h1 class="msg error">Email delivery failed…</h1>');
      }
    }
  ?>
    <!-- Form -->
    <form method="POST">
      <!--  Dropdown Menu-->
      <select name="drop_menu">
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="duck">Duck</option>
      </select>
      <!--  Send button-->
      <input type="submit" value="Send Form" />
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Notice that I added the tag **style**, for CSS styling. You shouldn´t use font tag, its bad practice. Actually you should use a different CSS file, but this should get you started.
Just change the **$to** variable to your email, and that´s it.

Some encapsulation should be added to the php code too, but as you might be new to this, this might work well for you.

I really recommend you to start reading about HTML5, CSS3 and PHP, a beginner guide will cover all the basics, all this is included.

Comment: You guys are frickin fast on the replies. I didn't expect the quick turnaround. I used the font tag because I will see the page on iPhone Safari, and I want to see the text in larger letters than H1. I will test the code when work slows down a bit. Thank you very much.

Comment: The drop down shows up, then the next line reads: "self close();"
The resulting email is sent successfully, but it doesn't print the selected value in the subject.
The resulting email subject is "I am a " without the selected "cat"
Anyone know what's off?

Comment: Is this your first code in php? If you are posting the result in the same php, you should wrap your code with a some POST checking, here´s the next edit.

Comment: The edit solved my problems. How can I apply the css tags to the form as well as the output?

Comment: ok, I'm good. Everything is working, however godaddy is batching the form emails, so I need the form to create and launch a mailto: URL in order to call my mail client. Instead of sending emails from the form, the form needs to populate a new email in my client. Thank you for the help.